# No entiendo esta clase para animar JFrames

Tags: java, hilos, interfaz-gráfica, jframe, animación

Esta clase contiene métodos para realizar una animación de *slide* en los componentes JFrame. Estaría muy agradecido si alguien me explica la lógica detrás de esto. Tengo entendido que utiliza *threads*, sin embargo aún no le encuentro sentido.

PD: He eliminado el código que corresponde al Formulario pues solo indica los componentes.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JFVentana extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private boolean estado = true;

    public JFVentana() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void Izq(JComponent componente, int milisegundos, int saltos, int parar) {
        (new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = componente.getWidth(); i >= parar; i -= saltos) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(milisegundos);
                        componente.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(i, componente.getHeight()));
                        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(componente);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("Error Thread Interrumpido: " + e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public static void Der(JComponent componente, int milisegundos, int saltos, int parar) {
        (new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = componente.getWidth(); i <= parar; i += saltos) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(milisegundos);
                        componente.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(i, componente.getHeight()));
                        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(componente);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println("Error Thread Interrumpido: " + e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

analicemos el código, y como decía "Jack, el destripador", vamos por partes.

Dentro de la función, tenemos esta linea:

```
( new Thread() {
```

Obviamente lo que hace es crear un Tread, lo precede de un paréntesis, para no declarar una variable (ej, *Thread hilo = new Thread()* ).

```
@Override // indica al compilador que está sobreescribindo el método run
public void run() {
```

el for, inicializa **i** con el ancho del componente y añade las condiciones de parada y aumento.

```
for( int i = componente.getWidth(); i <= parar; i += saltos) {
    try {
```

linea que pone a dormir el hilo

```
Thread.sleep( milisegundos );
```

acá le damos al componente su nueva dimensión, con **i** para el ancho ( que va aumentando con cada iteración) y **getHeight()** para el alto

```
componente.setPreferredSize( new Dimension( i, componente.getHeight() ));
```

luego actualiza el componente.

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(componente);
```

y finaliza con **}).start();**, que parece raro pero si o miras desde "lejos", se ve así:

```
( new Thread() { blabla } ).start();
```

osea metió todo el hilo dentro de paréntesis para darle el "start", es lo mismo que hacer:

```
Thread hilo = new Thread() 
blabla
hilo.start();
```

Espero no haber empeorado tu entendimiento!!

Comment: Pues en parte, si fue complicado entender jaja, pero lo logré. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Un placer poder ayudarte, espero que la próxima vez me salga una mejor explicación!!